# Special character Symbol replacing ''�"

Tags: java, utf-8

how to replace this symbol from java coding .. when i copied it into here its look like "�"
but in the coding it looks like a

> small square box

if i saved the code its asking to save as `'utf-8'` any one help me? Actually this is saved in the MYSQL Table while accession iam getting the problem

```
i will explain the scenario here..
```

> I have to replace the single quotes and new line and double quotes
>   characters in a string in java..
>
> when i was iterating, i found a string like 'RS approves President?s
>   Rule', i've checked in the database it is saved as 'RS approves
>   President[small square box]s Rule '....i first think that `'single
>   qoute'` and tried to replace,
>
> how can i replace this symbol..

Comment: Is the character set utf8 in the database?

Comment: @Shashank no it saved like small 'square box', i have to replace that with any other , but how to use it replace() of java..

Comment: @sakar this is the [Unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) and it probably indicates a transcoding defect in your code.

Comment: _....but in the coding it looks like small square box_..May be because your editor is not enabled to support UTF-8. If you are using eclipse, then you can change the encoding from Run Configuration -> Java application -> Common and select "UTF-8".

Comment: Wait a second, if it's saved as � in the DB, then you cannot just identify this with java... it would be a better way to do a workaround on the DB and on the code/method how you are adding these characters into the DB

Comment: @sabisabi its not saved as � , its saved as small square box

Comment: Well [] or � - the solution is to do a workaround on the DB

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more info on the flow of the string?

like:
input - webform
java - parses it or plain inserts it into the DB?
MySQL - stores the data

Make sure the input is set to (allow) UTF-8?
That the string in the Java is handled as UTF-8 
Also that MySQL is set to UTF-8